# Conditional Relationships between Two Tables in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-design

The following image shows a rough draft of my proposed database structure that I will develop for Django. Briefly, I have a list of ocean Buoys which have children tables of their forecast conditions and observed conditions. I'd like Users to be able to make a log of their surf sessions (surfLogs table) in which they input their location, time of surf session, and their own rating.

I'd like the program to then look in the buoysConditions table for the buoy nearest the user's logged location and time and append to the surfLog table the relevant buoyConditions. This will allow the user to keep track of what conditions work best for them (and also eventually create notifications for the user automatically).

I don't know what the name for this process of joining the tables is, so I'm having some trouble finding documentation on it. I think in SQL it's termed a join or update. How is this accomplished with Django?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you need help writing the actual django models?@Snek22

Comment: Will every surf log have a bouy condition associated with it? The proposed design looks sound, what do you mean by "joining the tables"? What exactly are you having trouble with

Comment: Are you trying to map this database design into Django (models) and want to perform joins on these tables ? Join are basically in SQL are fetching data between two or more tables.

Comment: I am trying to do this with Django models, yes. Each surfLog should have a condition associated with it, and that's where I'm having trouble: choosing the specific row in buoyConditions to link. For instance, imagine there's 3 buoys whose conditions get updated and stored every hour. In one day, I'll have 72 rows in the buoyConditions table. Now say a User logs a surf session at 10am on a beach near buoy #2. How do I link the specific row that matches this in buoyConditions to the surfLog table? Does that make sense?